# How to set condition for same attribute values in foreach loop - php - xml

Tags: php, loops, xml-parsing

i am getting data from xml feed and then using foreach loop inserting data in mysql.

but xml feed contains multiple items with same attribute like this

but what i want is ,

the addition of subitems of the attributes having same values

as xml shows the attribute tag1111 has 3 types of values

if i add something in foreach loop it gets replaced for every loop.

how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$requestUrl = "url";
$data = simplexml_load_file($requestUrl);
$i=0;
foreach($data->item as $subitem) {
    if(!in_array($data->item[$i]['promocode'], $arr_promocode))
        $arr_promocode[] = $data->item[$i]['promocode'];
    else{
        $key = array_search($data->item[$i]['promocode'], $arr_promocode);
        $data->item[$key]['clicks'] = $data->item[$key]['clicks'] + $subitem->clicks;
    }
    $arr_program[] = $data->item[$i]['program'];
    $arr_program_name[] = $data->item[$i]['program_name'];
    $clicks = $subitem->clicks;
    $total = $subitem->total;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: i have updated my answer after your comment. Please check now. The problem was just the two square brackets. Try now and i would love to know what happened.

Comment: what all together? How do you want?

Comment: helpful, after 9 years :O +1